# Create as many columns in a data frame as white spaces are in a string r

Tags: r

I have data separated by a white space:

```
question <- c("ENERO 602 1372 464 1505 S/C 610 1358 244 1424 S/C S/D S/D 1868 S/C",
          "FEBRERO 646 1526 504 1620 S/C 610 1443 251 1525 S/C S/D S/D 1873 S/C")
```

Data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(question)
```

The results are the following:

```
> data.frame(question)
                                                              question
1   ENERO 602 1372 464 1505 S/C 610 1358 244 1424 S/C S/D S/D 1868 S/C
2 FEBRERO 646 1526 504 1620 S/C 610 1443 251 1525 S/C S/D S/D 1873 S/C
```

There is only one column, do you know how to separate them?
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Read with `read.table` on the vector i.e. `read.table(text = question, header = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With space character, it is easier to read with `read.table` from `base R` and this will automatically assign the type of the columns based on its value

```
read.table(text = question, header = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is already vector as you have suggested above, the below will seperate into separate strings.

```
question %>% str_split(" ")
```